# Sending a string to a table based on the contents of another cell in the same row

Tags: excel, formula

[image]I'm trying to check if C4:C139 is empty and, if it is, send the contents of that particular row's A column to a table on the same work sheet.  The ultimate goal is to have a table showing what sites listed in the "A" column do not have UDAK (our organizations purchasing account numbers) information.  This will give us an easy reference to see who we need to contact to ask for the information.

Here is a picture if anyone cares to embed:https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjh6jcko6bzwjej/String%20to%20table.PNG

Comment: What you see in the picture is the source data.  There will be another table below that will contain the string of each A cell whose corresponding C cell is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C4),A4,"")
```

may serve (in your table and copied down to suit).

That's the `copied down to suit` part! The cell references are not absolute (not fixed, do not contain `$` signs) so adjust automatically. The column references `C` and `A` should not change - but they won't as long as the formula stays in the same column - but `4` (Row4) will adapt to `5` in the next row - and so on down.

Comment: That definitely works.  Given the nature of the formula, each row that does have data in the C column shows as a blank cell.  Now I just have to find a way to automatically hide those cells and consolidate the new table.

Comment: This all works.  Its not really the ideal way but maybe I've seen the limitation of Excel formulas just now.  Thanks for your help.